# Delphi & Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado

How can I use MS Access as a back-end database for a Delphi program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MS Access from Delphi is [straight forward](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/microsoft-access-and-borland-delphi.html).  ADO is supported in Professional and Enterprise/Architect SKUs.

I would recommend [saving the hash for your passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621/how-do-i-hash-a-string-with-delphi) in the database.  this way, when the user enters a user name and password, you hash that password and compare it to what's stored in the database.  This means you don't have an un-hashed version hanging around, so it's more secure.